# how to write data to Excel without changing the current format

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to overwrite data in excel sheet. The way I do it is by deleting the content from the the sheet and then writing range of data. The problem is when I write the data it deletes the cell format and then places my numbers as text. 
is there a way to keep the format which the user has defined so when I write data it uses the same format?

Comment: Post your code. We have no Idea how you write the data into excel. Which framework you use to manipulate excel? Ado.net? interop? open xml? or any third party libray ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll file. Add it in your project reference and in your Code as Using using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Then check the below code. Also to you this dll there should be Microsoft Excel Installed in the machine where this code is going to run.

```
 Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        excel.Workbooks.Add();
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = excel.ActiveSheet;
        int rowIndex = 2 ;
        worksheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "List Title";
        worksheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "Item Count";
        Console.WriteLine("Copying the contents to Excel");
        foreach (var list in listCollection)
        {

            worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, "A"] = list.Title;
            worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, "B"] = list.ItemCount;
            rowIndex++;
            //Console.Write("List Title: {0}", list.Title);
            //Console.WriteLine("\t"+"Item Count:"+list.ItemCount);

        }
        string fileName = string.Format(@"C:\FileName.xlsx");

        worksheet.SaveAs(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Export Completed");
       Console.ReadLine();
       excel.Quit();
       GC.Collect();
```

Comment: Thanks Akarsh for your reply. However, i will need to write range. such as 
MSExcel.Range first_cell = (MSExcel.Range)worksheet.Cells[startRow, column];
MSExcel.Range last_cell = (MSExcel.Range)worksheet.Cells[lastRow, column];
            worksheet.get_Range(first_cell, last_cell).Value2 = values;

Comment: what exactlly you need to do with Range. Can you please explain ?

Comment: I am trying to write column of data. However, when i do so i lose the column format which was specified by the user.

Comment: You can use my above code and modify only the format of it, The format can be changed on the loop. You can add the loop according to your need and data and rest of the code can be the same.

Comment: I solved that using pastespecial method. multiplying values by 1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.pastespecial.aspx